# MongoDB to trigger REST API springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, database-trigger

Is there any way to trigger REST API from mongodb ?
below is my mongo document

```
{
 _id : "123",
 "expiryTime" : "2020-01-30T00:00:00Z",
 "status" : "NEW"
}
```

I have an REST API which will mark status of all documents for which expiryTime reached as "OLD".

How to achieve this , can mongo call an API ?

Comment: No, MongoDB cannot trigger any API Rest.

Comment: can you suggest any other alternative to this??

Comment: Even if MongoDB contained a HTTP client - how should the call result in MongoDBs contents being changed?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't have any solution to this.

**Alternative solutions:**

*Schedule Tasks with Spring Boot*: You need to implement in your code such logic [look here](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-task-scheduling-with-scheduled-annotation/)

*UNIX*: You may schedule with [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) to execute commands / API rest periodically.

*Windows*: You may schedule with [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) to execute commands / API rest periodically.

You may write a program (Python, Java) to do:

```
Connect MongoDB
Check if any data expired for current date (query)
  - If yes, execute API rest for each expired data
  -- Remove expired data
  - If no, finish the execution
```